# How to make application in Zoom mode for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus?

Tags: ios, autolayout, ios9, zooming, iphone-6

I am facing issue regarding zoom mode which is available in iphone 6 and 6 Plus.

Display & Brightness -> View change to (Standard / Zoom) mode.

I want my application compatible to this Zoom mode as some issues are coming related to text used in app.

For more detail of Zoom mode 
https://support.apple.com/en-sa/HT203073

Answer (score 0):

The Zoom mode of iPhone 6/6 Plus scales the screen resolution of a 4-inch iPhone to fit the screen of the new devices. This is the same mode used by apps that aren't compatible with iPhone 6/6 Plus resolution. For example, an iPhone 6 has a virtual resolution of 1136 × 640 pixels running in zoom mode - the same of iPhone 5/5s.

If your app works fine on iPhone 5/5s, it should work fine on your iPhone 6/6 Plus with Zoom mode enabled.

[Reference](http://www.iphonehacks.com/2014/09/use-display-zoom-iphone-6-plus.html)